# Из-за работы тестером не хватает стимула и времени, чтобы перейти в программисты

Tags: тестирование

Мне нравится программировать. Волей случая я стал тестировщиком ПО, хотя проходил собеседование на разработчика. Тестирую уже 1,5 года, кажется надоело.. Хочется программировать и перейти в разряд разработчиков.
После работы уже мало сил что-то придумывать и программировать.

В итоге получается, что из-за работы тестером не хватает стимула и времени, чтобы перейти в программисты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне кажется, я что-то упускаю из внимания

Comment: один хороший тестер стоит 5ти программистов.

Comment: @eicto 5ти обычных программистов(кодеров), но 

1 хороший тестер = 1 хороший программист

Comment: А вот для лично для ТС, наверняка есть. 

@alhimic37, тут все просто. Если работа не нравится, то ее надо поменять (или просто сказать боссу об этом).

Comment: @avp, хороший совет

Comment: @eicto, согласен с вами

Answer (score 9):

Хороший тестер (то, что называется [Software Engineer In Test](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/what-does-software-engineer-in-test-do)) — это, в первую очередь, первоклассный программист. Я не знаю, как именно у вас сейчас построен рабочий процесс, но тесты порой сложнее разрабатывать, чем тестируемое приложение. Хочется программировать — начните, например, с автоматизации всей вашей рутины на работе. Или предложите вашей команде помощь в написании unit- и integration-тестов.

Comment: Ценный совет, @Котик_хочет_кушать, спасибо:)

Answer (score 2):

[@alhimic37](/users/14245/alhimic37)

Я тоже как и ты являюсь тестировщиком ПО. Устраивался разработчиком, но из-за того что ребята в команде пишут куда быстрее меня то я превратился в тестировщика. Анализируя почему все так пришел к тому что я слишком заостряюсь на вопросах вида "А что если подать сюда... ?". В то время ребята в команде, как правило, не парятся и просто решают задачу.

Я к тому что тебе уже ответили и ответили верно. "Хороший тестировщик в первую очередь хороший программер". С этим не возможно не согласиться. Да и если посмотреть на тестирование ПО и обеспечение качества в целом, то можно увидеть, что программирования у тестировщика тоже есть! Примеры: Автоматизация тестирования, автоматизация анализа выходных отчетов после программ, генерация тестовых примеров и тестовых данных.

Отличие тестировщика от программиста в том, что тестировщик пишет программу для людей, которая стремится сломать разрабатываемый код продукта. Этой программой для людей является набор тестовых сценариев. Пример: 1) Запустите программу 2) Откройте меню 3) Увидев пункт ... 4) Нажмите 5) Вы должны увидеть "...." иначе БАГ.

Да и сам процесс воспроизведения бага это очень увлекательный процесс. Добиться того чтобы баг превратился из Гейзенбага в элементарную последовательность действий приводящих к багу порою увлекательнее чем сама отладка программы. Да и разработчик после такой формулировки бага уже меньше дебажит, ибо за него уже проделали достаточно большую работу.

Тестировщик: это не хреново, это почетно!!!